# How to check if data insert is not null with NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a controller that when i insert data into the database it always inserted. Now i wanna check that if the data i create is null is must report an error.
Here is my code:

```
// create new car
export async function createCar (req, res) {
    const car = new Car({
      car_id: id,
      name: req.body.name,
      color: req.body.color,
      brand: req.body.brand,
    });
    
    return car
      .save()
      .then((newCar) => {
        return res.status(201).json({
          success: true,
          message: 'New car created successfully',
          Car: newCar,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({
          success: false,
          message: 'Server error. Please try again.',
          error: error.message,
        });
      });
  }
```

And i check on postman even i let Name is NULL is still inserted. Furthermore, how can i check that COLOR, BRAND if it's null must also report an error. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: For this some package their he first one is JOI and the other one is express-validator this is called Request Validation

Comment: You can use your own middleware function for validating the API. This link contains information about middle functions using the express framework: [https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

You can use middleware for POST requests for your URL or simply for POST requests.

Comment: Still have an issue let me know I'll explain further more

Comment: Could you post the code and steps to help me with this, i really appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah sure are you using node-express-mongoose right

Comment: if you are using mongoose you can define required inputs in the schema model ----> https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

Comment: Yes, i am using node-express, but my database is postgre SQL

Answer (score 1):

Kato, please follow my boilerplate. I created it with the best practices, and it also provides high-end JOI request validation.

A boilerplate for building production-ready RESTful APIs using Node.js, ExpressJs, Mongoose and Joi (Request Validation)

[Node-Express-Mongoose-Joi](https://github.com/smit-code/node-express-mongoose)

Comment: i check you github and i wonder where you can check Name, description of Book if it's null or not null.

Comment: Using joi, we can check whether our entire request/json is a number or a string. For a special case like email, there is a methods email() we can use to validate that it's a valid email address.

Answer (score 0):

For validate before insert

```
// Validate request
if (!req.body.name) 
{
  res.status(400).send
  ({
      message: "Name can not be empty!"
  });
  return;
} else if (!req.body.color)
{
   res.status(400).send
   ({
       message: "Color can not be empty!"
   });
    return;
} else if (!req.body.brand) 
{
    res.status(400).send({
       message: "Brand can not be empty!"
    });
    return;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).